# IFolderView::GetItemPosition returns E_NOTIMPL

Tags: shell, winapi, notimplementedexception

I'm trying to call the `IFolderView::GetItemPosition` method, which is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifolderview-getitemposition) and used by Raymond [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130318-00/?p=4933).  But it appears to be returning `E_NOTIMPL`, an outcome which is corroborated [here](http://qttabbar.sourceforge.net/?p=42). I was wondering if there's anything I can do or any newer alternatives I can call. Thanks.

Comment: Windows version?

Comment: I'm on 8.1.  Does it work in 10?

Comment: Are you doing this on the desktop IShellFolder or some other folder?

Comment: Another folder.  Not the desktop.

Comment: Which folder? Is it a standard folder or a 3rd-party shell namespace extension? Is the folder open in a Explorer window? Do you have access to its IShellBrowser?

Comment: It's just a regular document folder.  Other method calls work just fine on it.  Yeah, I think I have access to that.

Comment: It works fine for me on  **Windows 10 - 1803, 17134.765** (VS 2015, SDK 10)

Comment: hi,amt528  I follow the doc you provide,and I can access  the position of  icons in the desktop's view.Do you try to access on the desktop?

Comment: No, I just tried it in a folder.  Perhaps that's the problem.  Thanks for trying it out.

Comment: Maybe it's just a problem with folder, and I'll try to do that in folder later.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much.  But if that were the problem, wouldn't you expect an error different than E_NOTIMPL?

Comment: @amt528 hi, I can't reproduce your problem here. Can you post your code?